# Is it possible to include a video link in array? if yes, how so?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, arraylist

I've been trying to make a video playlist, basically, when one of them stops ends, the other one starts, when that ends, the original one starts. 1>2>1>2 etc repeatedly. I have attempted to do this by including the video links in an array however they don't show up at all. I only wish to use javascript for this.  My code:

```
<body onload="setFirstVideo()">
<video controls  onended="videoEnded()"
       src="">
</video>
```

```
var videoSources = new Array();

videoSources[0] = ['<video> <source src="http://courses.cs.cityu.edu.hk/cs2204/barbecue.mp4">,<source src="http://courses.cs.cityu.edu.hk/cs2204/barbecue.ogg"> </video>'];
videoSources[1] = [  "http://courses.cs.cityu.edu.hk/cs2204/cakemaking-s.mp4", "http://courses.cs.cityu.edu.hk/cs2204/cakemaking-s.ogg"];
var currentIndex = 0;

function setFirstVideo()
{
    var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
        myVideo.src = videoSources[currentIndex];
}

function videoEnded(){
    var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
    currentIndex = (currentIndex+1) % videoSources.length;
    myVideo.src = videoSources[currentIndex];
    myVideo.load();
    myVideo.play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the right idea. The only thing that jumps out as no good is in your first one, just include the URL, not HTML.

Or, as it looks like you have two sources, what you can't use the `myVideo.src` attribute to set them. Instead, you'll need to append them as children.

Either way, be consistent. I would recommend you probably do an array of arrays with just the URLs:

```
videoSources = [
  ['example.com/video1.mp4', 'example.com/video1.ogg'],
  ['example.com/video2.mp4', 'example.com/video2.ogg']
];
```

Then, when you go to load the video, instead of setting `myVideo.src`, remove all of `myVideo`'s children, and then add new ones:

```
var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
myVideo.innerHTML = ''; // fast way to empty children
videoSources[currentIndex].forEach(url => {
  const source = document.createElement('source');
  source.src = url;
  myVideo.appendChild(source);
});
```

Doing something like this should allow you to dynamically set the sources for your videos. Just make sure both functions do it this way (or better yet, make a common function they both call) and you should be pretty good.

Comment: Could you maybe give me a demo using the links? maybe a jsfiddle, because it doesnt seem to work still